# Preposition after 'deluged'

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, predicate-frames

I am aware that the word deluged means two things:

1. Flooded with water
2. Overwhelmed

The question I want to ask is its usage in a sentence. Would I say 'deluged with' or 'deluged by' something? In other words, should I use 'by' or 'with' when using the word 'deluged'? Thank you.

Princeton Review "Word Smart" provides an example that says 'was deluged by phone calls'.

According to numerous dictionaries such as Oxford, Cambridge, and Merriam Webster, the common usage is 'deluged with'.

On the other hand, [Oxford Dictionary of Difficult Words](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&pg=PA119&dq=%22deluged%20by%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22deluged%20by%22&f=false) shows *both*, with different objects.

Does the preposition change, depending on the object?

Comment: Yes, I did check some dictionaries.

Comment: It is called 'Word Smart' by "The Princeton Review'.

Comment: Oh my goodness. This is study for SAT or TOEFL? I used to send in correction after correction to Princeton about the errors in their texts. They are not the best to study from IMHO. I tutored on those as well as GRE, GMAT, etc. Here is an [Ngrams comparing the 2 usages.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deluged+with%2C+deluged+by&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeluged%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cdeluged%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bdeluged%20by%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BDeluged%20by%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Try [The Oxford Dictionary of Difficult Words](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&pg=PA119&dq=%22deluged+by%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGlNG3yNPjAhUHWq0KHQnwCfMQ6AEINzAC#v=onepage&q=%22deluged%20by%22&f=false)

Comment: Okay, I guess I should trust the dictionaries since the book may have errors.

Comment: According to the Ngrams I cited, both have currency. "Deluge with" is more common.

Comment: @PhilSweet _That_ has both. Do you think that maybe there is different usage depending on the object i.e. rains/work etc? Looks like we have the beginnings of a good question that many users would close down on first blush as "lack of research", or General Reference.

Comment: @Cascabel Yes, I've been perusing nGrams and I think there is a split. Oddly, a following definite article seems to push the trend towards *by* - something to do with specificity and possibly the  countability of the object. Deluged by a rogue wave.

Comment: This is reasonable question with a simple answer.  It surprises me that people seem reluctant to answer.

Comment: @Patriot It appears that _possibly_ there are more complexities to the question than can be solved with just a look-up. Feel free to steal whatever Phil and I have said here and turn it into an answer. Ain't no shame in that.

Comment: @Cascabel You guys need to see what prepositions collocate with *deluged* in COCA, at least. Right now it’s *with* at 176 and *by* at 28, and nothing else gets more than one hit. Pretty sure the 28 aren't somehow “wrong” though.

Comment: @tchrist SO I guess you are saying that there are enough hits with both prepositions in both circumstances. How can we explain to the OP the discrepancies between the majority of the dictionaries (save Oxford weird words), and COCA?// I guess that basically we are now trying to explain the Oxford use in the linked example by PhilS..

Comment: @Cascabel It’s one thing to have a deluge of frogs raining down upon you like some Biblical plague but quite another to deluge someone with squishy questions. :) Being deluged by something is not the same "thing" as being deluged with something. You could be deluged BY a storm WITH water. The storm deluges you with water. The water did not deluge you; only the storm did so. But historically you could be deluged in tears of grief.

Comment: @tchrist Worthy of a _real_ answer.

Comment: @Cascabel I wouldn't want to lose my head: *après moi le déluge*, et tout ça. The unspoken problem here is that the asker needs to understand that *deluged* (and for that matter *inundated* as well) is of a far different register and frequency than  that of *flooded*, despite sharing syntactic properties.

Comment: I know there is not not a lot of meat here, but maybe there is enough gristle  to do a community wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We use by, not with, to talk about the action of something:
>
> He got into the house by breaking the window. (action)
>
> Not: … with breaking the window.
>
> We use with, not by, to refer to the object or instrument that we use
>   to do something!
>
> He broke the window with a rock. (object/instrument)

By: Cambridge Dictionary - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/by

Essentially, with *by*, there is a matter of being once removed from the event itself, whereas with *with*, it is directly embroiled in the event. In a comment, I suggested "deluged by a rogue wave". The wave no longer exists, it being destroyed in the event, so *by* seems more apt to me.

I would use *with* in "deluged [with/by] phone calls" if the issue was mostly about the inability to handle the incoming calls. But I can see "deluged by phone calls" if the focus is on the people who are calling or the issue that precipitated the calls - as in "their announcement outraged the public, and for days they were deluged by phone calls and mail." After all, there are two ends to a phone call, and you can choose the preposition which best suits the end receiving focus.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That makes so much sense. Never thought of it like that.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at it (without going through all the comments).

It really depends on agency (i.e. blame -- who's fault it is). Consider:

- Deluged by puppies

or:

- Deluged with puppies

Now. Everyone loves puppies, so you can hardly blame them for your distress. Someone must have left them on your doorstep, or sent them through the post, or maybe you just allowed your dog to get pregnant (again). **But it's not the puppies fault.** You have been deluged **with** puppies, not **by** puppies.

On the other hand:

- Deluged by spammers

or:

- Deluged with spammers

You have my sympathy if you find yourself unable a cope due to a surfeit of spammers. However, it is unlikely that some mean soul sent them through the post, just to annoy you. Spammers have agency. They could have decided to stay in bed, or get a proper job, or something. You have been deluged **by** spammers, not deluged **with** spammers.

OK. Now you can jump on me. [Waits for the deluge]

Comment: Awww,...puppies? ...couldn't you have at least included a gratuitous link to 101 Dalmatians?

Comment: @Cascabel I don't know what came over me. I'm not even drunk.

Comment: I love puppies..

Comment: I could change it to kittens.

Comment: It's OK. I'm gonna go back to watching 101 Dalmatians with the kids:-)

Comment: A better answer than others here, but lacking any supporting reference.

Answer (score 0):

[Deluge:](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/deluge_2)

***deluge somebody/something (with something)*** [usually passive] to send or give someone or something a large number of things at the same time.

> - We have been deluged with applications for the job.
> - He was deluged with phone calls from friends and colleagues.
> - Applicants deluged the office with calls.

(OLD)

[Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deluged%20with%2Cdeluged%20by&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeluged%20with%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeluged%20by%3B%2Cc0) shows both usages but *deluged by* is less commonly used.

As noted the [Oxford Dictionary](https://books.google.it/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&pg=PA119&dq=%22deluged%20by%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu8aGmsNTjAhWCKewKHeIIBEEQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22deluged%20by%22&f=false) suggest both usages:

> - cottages were deluged by heavy rains.